# Dismiss alert dialog after time

Tags: java, android

How do I add an automatic dismiss dialog after a time to the show alert function?

```
public void showAlert(String title, String message, Integer seconds) {
        new IonAlert(context, IonAlert.SUCCESS_TYPE)
                .setTitleText(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Handler` class provides a method called `postDelayed()`. It allows us to dealy an event (in your case, event is to dismiss the dialog).

```
    public void showAlert(String title, String message, Integer seconds) {
        final IonAlert ionAlertDialog = new IonAlert(context, IonAlert.SUCCESS_TYPE)
            .setTitleText(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .show();
    
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ionAlertDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }, seconds ? seconds * 1000 : 5000); //default 5sec
    }
```